# Check if a member variable exists in an Object from superClass?

Tags: java, inheritance

My classes are defined in a way like this

```
class SuperClass
{
  protected boolean hasProperty;
}

class SubOne extends SuperClass
{

  protected Property prop;   

  SubOne()
  {
    this.hasProperty=true;
    this.prop=new Property(); 
  }
}

class SubTwo extends SuperClass
{
  SubTwo()
  {
    this.hasProperty=false;
  }
}
```

I needed the different objects of SubOne and SubTwo in a single Array, because I want objects of both classes interact with each and every one else and also I actually have four SubClasses(I've taken only two here for example), so I wanted to put them all in single Array. I used the following thing.

```
SuperClass[] superClass={
  new SubOne(),
  new SubTwo()
}
```

Now, while iterating the loop, if I write the following, it gives me error. I've spent time in searching for soution, but I couldn't find it.

```
for(Superclass superObj:superClass)
{
  if(superObj.hasProperty)
    System.out.print(superObj.prop.something);
    //when hasProperty is false, this statement should not be called, 
    //but compiler gives error
  else
    System.out.print("Something");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried casting `superObj` to `SubOne`?

Comment: @RamenChef I thought this but I'm storing all SubOne and SubTwo type objects in single Array. So, how do I know whether to cast it into SubOne or SubTwo?

Comment: By whether `hasProperty` is true. You can also use the `instanceof` keyword. I'm also posting another solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to have a method in the superclass called `getProperty` which can be called from any instance once the presence of the property is verified. In the superclass, the method can return null or throw an exception; override it in the subclass to return the actual property. Like so:

```
class SuperClass
{
    protected boolean hasProperty;

    protected Property getProperty()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

class SubOne extends SuperClass
{
    protected Property prop;   

    SubOne()
    {
        this.hasProperty=true;
        this.prop=new Property(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected Property getProperty()
    {
        return prop;
    }
}

class SubTwo extends SuperClass
{
    SubTwo()
    {
        this.hasProperty=false;
    }
}
```

And the code for the iteration would be as follows:

```
if (superObj.hasProperty)
    System.out.println(superObj.getProperty().something);
else
    System.out.println("Something");
```

The advantage of this over a template method is that it works for any application of the properties without needing to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

An oop solution would be using a template method, for instance:

```
class SuperClass {
    protected void templateMethod(){
        System.out.print("Something");
    }
}

class SubOne extends SuperClass {

    protected Property prop;   

    SubOne() {
        this.hasProperty=true;
        this.prop=new Property(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void templateMethod() {
        System.out.print(this.prop.something);
    }
}

class SubTwo extends SuperClass {...}
```

Then your other code can just call:

```
for(Superclass superObj : superClass) {
    superObj.templateMethod();
}
```

---

Another solution, that allows you to provide a context dependant default value uses `Optional`:

```
class SuperClass {
    protected Optional<Property> prop = Optional.empty();
}

class SubOne extends SuperClass {
    ...
    SubOne() {
        this.prop = Optional.of(new Property());
    }
    ...
}
```

Then use like:

```
for(Superclass superObj : superClass) {
    String value = superObj.prop
                       .map(Property::getSomething)
                       .orElse("Something");

    System.out.print(value);
}
```

Assuming `Property` has this getter for the `something` field (otherwise you could use `p -> p.something` instead of `Property::getSomething`).

Answer (score 1):

The compile won't let you access `prop` because as far as the compile knows, `superObj` is an instance of SuperClass and not an instanceof SubOne.

I think you would be better off just checking `instanceof SubOne` and removing the `hasProperty` flag.

```
    for (SuperClass superObj : superArray) {
        if (superObj instanceof SubOne) { // check instanceof
            System.out.println(((SubOne)superObj).prop.something); // cast
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Something");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this way is better than the other answers. It is more java like, vs JavaScript like. Which means more secure, and if an error occurs, it will be easier to spot.